# Angular JS 1.5 module controller query(?)

Tags: angularjs

I have inherited code and am having problems editing it. I want to edit it on the backend (JS) so I only get a certain array to cycle through on the front end (HTML).

So my code is like this:
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('myappcontroller', function ($rootScope, $scope, myParam)

$scope.myParams = [];

$scope.loadall = function(){
myParam.query (function (result){
$scope.myParams = result.content;
});

};

$scope.loadall();

});
```

on the front end I have

```
<div ng-repeat="myParam in myParams" 
. . . . .
```

myParams is a json string/array that could resemble [{"id":6,"user"{"id":10,"firstname":"Albert"}}]

As-is the code cycles through everything and prints it out. But if I change it to

```
myParam.query({"id":11},function(result){ . . .
```

it breaks and returns nothing even though there is an entry where id=11. How would I fix this . . . query . . . filter? What is "query"? I have seen "get" and "find". I cannot find what those are called. What is "myParam" passed into the controller? Is that just a parameter? Maybe if I knew the Angular JS terminology I could do better help/api searching.

Comment: `myParam` is a service that is being injected, not to be confused with `myParams` which is where the result of the call to `query()` is being stored.  `query()` is a function defined as a method of the `myParam` service.  It doesn't appear that you are calling that function correctly in your changed code.

Comment: so I need to find the myParam service and either edit the query() function to accept the "id" parameter to filter it down or create another function "query_by_id" so it accepts that id as a parameter? if so would the Angular JS of "query_by_id({"user.id":10},function(result) . . . be correct as I have the service result sampel above? is it "user.id" or "user:id" or ?Thanks

Comment: To the first part, yes you would have to find the `myParam` service and see what methods are available.  To the second part, if your function is `query_by_id`, then you would probably just pass the value you want to search for, not the field and value (since the field is implicitly suggested to be `id` by the function name).